# Why does my openssl connection fail with elliptic curve cipher ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA?

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection, ubuntu

I am using openssl example server and client with specific cipher in ubuntu 14.10 pc. The openssl version is 1.0.1.

When I use the RC4-SHA cipher in both sides, the connection is established successfully. However, when I use ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA or some other elliptic curve cipher, I get the following error:

```
3074328252:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:762:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 163 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

Is there some specific reason why this happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

That's because you are trying to use an **ECDH** cipher suite, and not and **ECDHE** cipher suite.

- **ECDHE-RSA:** the server's certificate contains an RSA public key; the server generates on-the-fly a new elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman key pair, and signs the public part, that the server sends to the client.
- **ECDH-RSA:** the server's certificate already contains an elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman public key; it is not generated on-the-fly; the *Certificate Authority* that issued (signed) the server's certificate used RSA.

Since your server's certificate contains a RSA key, you cannot use any "ECDH" cipher suite, only "ECHDE" cipher suites. (And that's fine ! ECDHE cipher suites actually provide [Forward Secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy), which is a good thing to have, and ECDH cipher suites don't do that.)

Comment: @Tom Leek do you know how to generate the certificate for the latter case (ECDH-RSA). Hours of search has not helped. To summarize, I want to generate the fixed DH certificate, where I can embed the DH public key into an RSA cert. Much thanks!